# jQuery find all id's that begin with a defined string and end in a number

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, selector

I would like to do something like this:

```
jqueryElement.find('divIdWithIterator**').each(...);
```

where `'divIdWithIterator**'` matches all elements with ids that start with `'divIdWithIterator'` and end in a number, such as:

`divIdWithIterator1, divIdWithIterator2, divIdWithIterator26`

What is a good way to do this in jQuery?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no regular expression selector.

You could use the [attribute-starts-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/), then [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) the results and check for numeric endings using [`search()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search)

Eg

```
var divs = jqueryElement.find('[id^="divIdWithIterator"]').filter(function(index){
    return this.id.search(/\d$/) != -1;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Following: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

To find the elements whose id begin with "divIdWithIterator":

```
$('input[id^="divIdWithIterator"]')
```

And then avoid to have other elements that begin with "divIdWithIterator" and you don't want to select

Comment: How do I do this using "find()" on an element instead of search the whole page?

Comment: find('input[id^="divIdWithIterator"]')