# jQuery selector certain string and number from 0 to 9 after it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this HTML elements

```
            <button id="btn7">7</button>
            <button id="btn8">8</button>
            <button id="btn9">9</button><button id="btnMulti">*</button>
            <button id="btn4">4</button>
            <button id="btn5">5</button>
            <button id="btn6">6</button><button id="btnDiv">/</button>
            <button id="btn1">1</button>
            <button id="btn2">2</button>
            <button id="btn3">3</button><button id="btnPlus">+</button>
            <button id="btn0">0</button>
            <button id="clear">C</button>
            <button id="clearEntry">CE</button><button id="btnMinus">-</button>
            <button id="equal">=</button>
```

how can i select all button elements with attribute id that contains "btn" and some number after it ? In other words - **buttons: "btn[0-9]"**. It should be something like this:

```
$(':button[id^="btn"]').match(/[0-9]/);
```

Comment: Try, $('button[id^="btn"]')

Comment: It works but it also select other buttons like "btnMinus".

Comment: This can help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878342/jquery-find-all-ids-that-begin-with-a-defined-string-and-end-in-a-number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.filter()` to filter the ids which have number in their id attributes. For this you can use a callback in the filter function use a regex:

```js
$('button').filter(function() {
  var rg = /\d/g;
  if (rg.test(this.id)) {
    return this;
  }
}).css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn7">7</button>
<button id="btn8">8</button>
<button id="btn9">9</button>
<button id="btnMulti">*</button>
<button id="btn4">4</button>
<button id="btn5">5</button>
<button id="btn6">6</button>
<button id="btnDiv">/</button>
<button id="btn1">1</button>
<button id="btn2">2</button>
<button id="btn3">3</button>
<button id="btnPlus">+</button>
<button id="btn0">0</button>
<button id="clear">C</button>
<button id="clearEntry">CE</button>
<button id="btnMinus">-</button>
<button id="equal">=</button>
```

You can use a var to hold the specific selector:

```js
var btn = $('button').filter(function() {
  var rg = /\d/g;
  if (rg.test(this.id)) {
    return this;
  }
});


btn.css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn7">7</button>
<button id="btn8">8</button>
<button id="btn9">9</button>
<button id="btnMulti">*</button>
<button id="btn4">4</button>
<button id="btn5">5</button>
<button id="btn6">6</button>
<button id="btnDiv">/</button>
<button id="btn1">1</button>
<button id="btn2">2</button>
<button id="btn3">3</button>
<button id="btnPlus">+</button>
<button id="btn0">0</button>
<button id="clear">C</button>
<button id="clearEntry">CE</button>
<button id="btnMinus">-</button>
<button id="equal">=</button>
```

Comment: You are welcome @StoyanPetkov. Good to see you here at SO. see you soon again.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the filter created by James Padolsey, Hope it helps

http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/

Add this in a file after jQuery

```
jQuery.expr[':'].regex = function(elem, index, match) {
    var matchParams = match[3].split(','),
        validLabels = /^(data|css):/,
        attr = {
            method: matchParams[0].match(validLabels) ? 
                        matchParams[0].split(':')[0] : 'attr',
            property: matchParams.shift().replace(validLabels,'')
        },
        regexFlags = 'ig',
        regex = new RegExp(matchParams.join('').replace(/^s+|s+$/g,''), regexFlags);
    return regex.test(jQuery(elem)[attr.method](attr.property));
}
```

Usage:

```
// Select all elements with an ID starting a vowel:
$(':regex(id,^[aeiou])');

// Select all DIVs with classes that contain numbers:
$('div:regex(class,[0-9])');

// Select all SCRIPT tags with a SRC containing jQuery:
$('script:regex(src,jQuery)');

// Yes, I know the last example could be achieved with 
// CSS3 attribute selectors; it's just an example...
```

**Update 2:**

You can use for your problem: `$('button:regex(id,btn[0-9])')`

Please find the updated [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VeYeaV)

Comment: It doesn't work. It throws an exception: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: regex.

Comment: check updated answer. Check the console logs for the objects selected

Comment: Thanks mate it work good but i prefer to use @Jai answer. It is simple and it does not need writing custom jQuery expr. I appritiate your effort. Again thanks a lot !